# Remove the input methods on windows 10 (not showing in languages)

Tags: windows, windows-10

my newly installed windows 10 is giving me a nightmare of having 4 different English keyboards..
Any idea what is going on here?

The list of my input methods showing
[image: The list of my input methods showing]

The input method I have in my English language
[image: The input method I have in my English language]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you follow detailed steps as below to remove all English keyboards first and then re-install the needed one of English keyboards trough Settings.

Here's how to remove the English keyboard. Please follow the steps below :

- From the Start menu, search for powershell.
- Right-click Windows Powershell in the search results and choose Run as administrator.
- Type or copy/paste each of the following commands at the command
  prompt, and then press Enter. In the following commands,
   is the language tag the customer is trying to remove,
  such as en-US.

**Get-WinUserLanguageList**

(Take note of the LanguageTag for the language the customer is trying to remove.)

[image]

And then please insert the following commands in PS

```
$LangList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$MarkedLang = $LangList | where LanguageTag -eq "<languagecode>"
$LangList.Remove($MarkedLang)

Set-WinUserLanguageList $LangList -Force
```

[image]

After remove all the English keyboards through above steps, you can install needed English keyboard through **Settings**->**Time & Language**-> **Language**-> **Preferred languages**

[image]